# 'int' object is not callable(14)

Tags: python

I've had to debug this piece of code however i'm stuck on this bit and can't seem to find the issue.

My Code:

```
def inputInt(message):
    num = int(input(message))

    return num()

myNum = inputInt("Please enter a number:")

print(myNum * myInt)
```

Comment: Just `return num` instead of `return num()`.

Comment: use a little debugging before posting quesitons and also refer to python documentations or tutorials before asking a question .

Answer (score 2):

Two things to change.
Remove the calling `num()` since you've defined `num` as an integer before.
Give the value you want to the variable `myInt`.

```
def inputInt(message):
    num = int(input(message))
    return num

myNum = inputInt("Please enter a number:")
myInt = 2    #initialize myInt with desired value.
print(myNum * myInt)
```